# load jar/dex dynamically from an android app

Tags: java, android, classloader, dalvik, dex

Hi I am using an android app (Scheme Droid) based on **jscheme**, but if you're not familiar with it, maybe you are familiar with **Clojure**. In any case those provide access to the virtual machine (**jvm, dalvik**). On a computer (any arch or OS) I can dynamically load a class that i have compiled myself. But when I try on android (loading a dex'ed jar) I run into problems I can't fix:

```
> (define inner-url-array (array java.net.URL.class (java.net.URL. "file:///sdcard/Test.jar")))
# (file:///sdcard/Test.jar)
> (define systemClassLoader (ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader))
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]]
> (define arrlist (array java.lang.Class.class java.net.URL.class))
# (class java.net.URL)
> (define classLoaderClass java.net.URLClassLoader.class)
class java.net.URLClassLoader
> (define method (.getDeclaredMethod class LoaderClass  "addURL" arrlist))
protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
> (.setAccessible method #t)
#null
> (.invoke method systemClassLoader inner-url-array)
Expected receiver of type java.net.URLClassLoader, but got dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
```

the problem is therefore `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader` and even if I try to cast to `URLClassLoader` class, it refuses. Then I tried to use the `dalvik.system.DexClassLoader` instead

```
> (import "dalvik.system.*")
# t
> (define classloader (DexClassLoader. "/sdcard/Test.jar" "/sdcard" #null (.getParent (ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader))))
```

and I get this error now!:

> Optimized data directory /sdcard is not owned by the current user. Shared storage cannot protect your application from code injection attacks.

Why would it refuse to write to sdcard? and is there another solution to load a jar file like that or at least to extend the classpath for the app?

Answer (score 1):

> Why would it refuse to write to sdcard?

The error message would be for a read operation, not a write operation.

As to why, the error message is fairly self-explanatory. Google does not want apps loading code from an untrusted source, such as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> and is there another solution to load a jar file like that or at least to extend the classpath for the app?

Have the hosting app download the DEX into [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) for the app, validate that the DEX is not tampered with (e.g., have the DEX be packaged in a signed JAR that you then validate), then load the DEX from there.

Note that dynamic code loading like this may violate the terms of service for your chosen app distribution channel(s), should you be planning on distributing anything based upon this.

Comment: "Have the hosting app download the DEX into internal storage for the app". how would one do that? of course the internal storage is a no-go for any other app so copy/paste won't work. the hosting app doesn't download stuff

Comment: @francogrex: "the hosting app doesn't download stuff" -- then talk to the developers of the hosting app, and ask them to add something to allow you to do what you are trying to do.